# My keyboard doesn't work

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I am new to Ubuntu and I used it in a virtual machine for the university and I have decided to install it on the computer, the problem is that the laptop keyboard does not work.  It works for me in BIOS, Windows and everywhere except Ubuntu.  I don't know what to do, I have tried things that I have found on the Internet but nothing has worked for me.  On the Lenovo website, the only drivers for the laptop are for Windows 11. I would appreciate your help.  Thank you
Edit 1: The Ubuntu version is 22.10 and the laptop model is Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 ProX 14IAH7. One strange thing is that the keys to raise and lower the brightness work for me, the rest does not.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Can you please provide the make and model of the computer? This will help us figure out what's wrong. Also, please be specific about what you've already tried so that people aren't suggesting solutions that you know already don't work. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1459300/edit) and add all of the above information as well as the version of Ubuntu you are trying to install.

Comment: @mchid have already edited it with more information

Comment: @user68186 I have added more information

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like [the keyboard doesn't always work with kernels older than 5.2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_Yoga_Slim_7_Pro_X_(14ARH7)#Keyboard). Currently, Ubuntu Kinetic (22.10) is running [kernel version 5.19](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=kinetic&searchon=names&keywords=linux-image-generic).

Ubuntu [Lunar (23.04)](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) uses [kernel 6.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lunar&searchon=names&keywords=linux-image-generic) but it isn't officially supported here on Askubuntu until April (next month). You could download the iso now and install it early but keep in mind that it may have bugs. You would be encouraged to file a bug report for any issues, and any questions or issues will be off topic here on Askubuntu until the official release date in April.

22.10 will be EOL soon so you would have to upgrade to 23.04 in a couple of months anyhow.

Similar to 22.10, 23.04 is an interim release with 9 months of support. You will be expected to upgrade to 23.11 after that or in November when 23.11 is released.

24.04 will be the next LTS (Long Term Support) release and this version will be officially supported for 5 years.

Comment: Personally, I would go ahead and install 23.04 now. Again, it might have some bugs because the official release is next month. The reason it will be off topic here until April is because the devs would rather people file bug reports for any issues now so they can get them worked out before April.